# Flyte won't run in parallel

Tags: python, workflow, flyte

I'm new to flyte, trying to do quite simple things at the moment.

So I'm trying to to run multiple independant tasks in parallel, which, if I understand [the documentation](https://docs.flyte.org/en/latest/api/flytekit/generated/flytekit.map_task.html), is exactly the purpose of `map_task`.

However, so far I've been unable to make flyte actually run them in parallel.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```py
from flytekit import map_task, task, workflow

@task
def do_something(value: str) -> str:
    print(f"launched: {value}", flush=True)
    time.sleep(60)  # fakes long process time
    return f"{value}-processed"


@workflow
def do_multiple_things() -> list[str]:
    values = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
    return map_task(do_something)(value=values)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give more context please? How are you trying to run it? Is this running in remote (like on a live Flyte backend) or is this a local run? Local runs will not actually do parallel just yet. (Making flytekit execute local runs in parallel is part of a broader project that we have plans for some day, but no definite timeline).

A side note however, as of this writing (circa early 2024) there is a newer version of map task that we are steadily moving towards. If you could, I would suggest using this instead.

```
from flytekit.experimental import map_task
```

At some point the main map task will become this one (though we will keep the experimental import in place for compatibility).

Comment: Turns out that's indeed the issue: I was running the workflow locally. Thanks a lot for your help